# Get eventbrite attendes of a particular order id with personal oauth token

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, eventbrite

I am trying to integrate eventbrite with infusionsoft. I used eventbrite webhook to get the order api_url once an order is placed on my event. Using that api_url and personal oauthtoken, i am able to get the details of the particular order by passing the token "api_url?token=xxxxx"

This is the json response of the webhook after the order is placed

```
{"config": {"action": "order.placed", "user_id": "xxxxx", "endpoint_url":"http://example.com", "webhook_id": "xxxx"}, "api_url": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/xxxx/"}
```

I am passing the personal token to the order api_url "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/xxxx?token=xxxx"

The json response got from the above is

```
{
"resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/orders/xxxx/", 
"id": "xxxxx", 
"changed": "2015-09-09T09:41:31Z", 
"created": "2015-09-09T09:41:30Z", 
"costs": {
    "payment_fee": {
        "currency": "GBP", 
        "display": "\u00a30.00", 
        "value": 0
    }, 
    "gross": {
        "currency": "GBP", 
        "display": "\u00a30.00", 
        "value": 0
    }, 
    "eventbrite_fee": {
        "currency": "GBP", 
        "display": "\u00a30.00", 
        "value": 0
    }, 
    "tax": {
        "currency": "GBP", 
        "display": "\u00a30.00", 
        "value": 0
    }, 
    "base_price": {
        "currency": "GBP", 
        "display": "\u00a30.00", 
        "value": 0
    }
}, 
"name": "test67 test67", 
"first_name": "test67", 
"last_name": "test67", 
"email": "test67@gmail.com", 
"status": "placed", 
"time_remaining": null, 
"event_id": "xxxx"
```

}

Following is the code i am using to retrieve the json response

```
$url = $api_url.'?token=xxxx';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The problem is it only gives the basic information of the event. It does not give the attendees information in response. Can you help me with an idea or example to retrieve the attendees list belonging to a specific order id?
And is it possible to get the attendees list only using the personal oauth token?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Hi Dan Thanks for your suggestion. I have posted the code now. Can you help me on this?